# Tomcat10 cannot start bootstrap.jar not found

Tags: java, tomcat

I compiled a Servlet with java 15 and tried to run it with Tomcat 10 but got the error:

"java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Servlet1 has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime"

Looking at the Tomcat Properties I noticed Tomcat uses Java 8 that is installed also on my PC.

So I went to the Tomcat Properties under the Java tab and put down jdk-15.0.1\bin\jvm.dll
-> Tomcat didn't start anymore.

I noticed that in the same properties under the Java tab, there is "Java Classpath" but it's value was
Tomcat-Dir\bin\bootstrap.jar (I think). Then I changed this to jdk-15.0.1\bin (and variations thereof).

Now to my problem - Tomcat doesn't start anymore "ClassNotFoundException ... Bootstrap" I can change back the path to the JVM by checking "Use default", but I don't remember exactly the path under "Java Classpath". Can someone tell me what the default value needs to be here for Tomcat10. I would like to at least be able to start Tomcat again.

[I'm talking about this Tab in the Tomcat properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAk7L.png)

Comment: By default the classpath should just contain `bootstrap.jar` and `tomcat-juli.jar` (in Tomcat's installation folder). Can you check the architecture (32/64-bits) of your `tomcat10.exe` (run `tomcat10.exe version` in an administrator `cmd`) executable and Java 15 executable (`java -version`)? My guess is: you have a mix of 32-bit and 64-bit executables.

Comment: For Tomcat10.exe I get "Win32" & for Java it says "64-Bit Server VM". So I installed the incorrect Tomcat version. The installer is called "32-bit/64-bit Windows Service Installer (pgp, sha512)". I didn't see a way to choose 32 or 64 in the installation. But also, initially it worked despite of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are describing (immediate service start failure, nothing in Tomcat's logs and a short line in `commons-daemon.log`) happens when there is a mismatch between the architecture of the [Procrun service application](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/procrun.html) (installed as `bin\tomcat10.exe` in your Tomcat installation) and the architecture of the `jvm.dll`: a 32-bit executable cannot load a 64-bit library and viceversa.

You can confirm it with `tomcat10.exe version` (works only in an administrator `cmd`)) and `java -version`.

To solve this you need to download the complete Apache Commons Daemon distribution for Windows (cf. [download area](https://downloads.apache.org/commons/daemon/binaries/windows/)) and replace `tomcat10.exe` with the appropriate `prunsrv.exe` executable (there are two versions in the zip archive).

Regarding which libraries should be in Tomcat's classpath, you just need `bin\bootstrap.jar` and `bin\tomcat-juli.jar` in your server's installation folder.

**Remark**: The Windows MSI installer for Tomcat contains both `prunsrv.exe` versions, but installs only one depending on the architecture of the Java executable you choose during installation. Probably you have a 32-bit Java 8 and 64-bit Java 15. For a long time the [java.com](https://www.java.com/pl/download/) page automatically proposed the 32-bit version of Java.